# How to Show iPad's Keyboard when i click Input box from an ePub?

Tags: html, ipad, uikeyboard, epub, ibooks

Can anyone suggest me how to show iPad's keyboard for entering text when clicking on a input box through HTML JavaScript?

For an ePub viewed in iBook app on iPad.
In the ePub file, there is an input box has to be filled by the reader (user).

Looking for something to show iPad UI KeyBoard from HTML Form

I could not find the event/function call to do this.

Any Help/suggestion will be appreciated.

-

Thanks & Regards,

SaRaVaNaN.N

Answer (score 2):

N,

do you still stuck on this question
I just found

```
<input type='color'>
```

can make iPad keyboard show, but I think **it's a bug**,
cause ePub3 is too new
There are so few documentations.
May I keep contact with you?

Comment: thank aelam,

i've designed it with javascript and given.

anyhow, thanks a lot for your answer. i'll check it later.


And, of course you can keep contact with me....


Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="color">
```

This hack doesn't work anymore on iOS 6.